# Where can I add command line in the NSIS script

Tags: nsis

I would add some command line to customize my NSIS intaller. I already read some topics, I know I must use `${GetParameters}` and `${GetOptions}`. But the NSIS script is very long do I put him somewhere in the OnInit function or in a section at the beginning of  the script ?

I want, for example, to add an --quiet command line which display all the pages except the license( something which seems to /S), I want to try something like that:

Var DisplayAllPages

Var DisplayLicense

`${GetParameters}` "quiet"

`${GetOptions}` "quiet" "--quiet"=DisplayLicense

But I don't Know where can I write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `${GetParameters}` and `${GetOptions}` in any function and/or section.

Only `.onInit` and sections are executed when the installer is started with `/S` so if you wish to turn silent mode off you need to put the code in `.onInit`.

If you are storing the result in a global variable then `.onInit` is also a good place to call them so that the information is available to the rest of the installer.